# Rails Scope Return Variable/Joins In Another Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm filtering off of role access for a module.

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user|
  if user.super_admin?
   self
  else
   region = Region.find_by(name: user&.role&.name)
   if region.present?
    joins(:location)
     .where(location_id: region.location_ids)
   end
 end
}
def viewable(user)
 return user.super_admin? || user&.role&.name == region.name
end
```

The scope works in the filter. In a nutshell needing to filter on either super_admin OR from the User if their role name matches the Region name that has locations that are present display all the events that are present. However...viewing is defined by the viewable method. So my question is how do I hit the else statement in the OR.

I tried just copying over the entirety of the scope over to viewable but I end up with

> undefined method `joins'

I'm coming up blanks on hitting the location from the user without using the join statement.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping this up just in case someone experiences this:

```
return user.super_admin? || user&.role&.name == location.region.name
```